# Adding X-Frame-Options header to all pages in MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, x-frame-options

I am trying to add the X-Frame-Options header (with value set to "DENY") into my MVC 4 application. I looked around and it seems [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130921220931/http://blog.codinginertia.com/130/prevent-clickjacking-in-asp-net-mvc) is the cleanest way to add for all pages.

However when I add this code it will not build.  With an error on `OnResultExecuting` of

> *"no suitable method found to override."*

```
public class XframeOptions : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(
          System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader(
            "X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    }
}
```

If this is the cleanest way to do this how can I resolve this error?  Is there a better way to handle this in an MVC 4 application?

Comment: This worked for me, but setting the property in <system.webServer> does not work. This is not the first time I've had settings in system.webServer seemingly ignored. Why would this be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you inherit from the [`correct class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
public class XframeOptions : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
```

In ASP.NET MVC 4 there's the Web API which has different namespace and since you haven't explicitly specified the namespace I guess that the compiler is picking the wrong class:

```
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
```

Answer (score 148):

There's no need for a custom HttpModule or ActionFilter if you need it for every page.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options details a much simpler solution:

To configure IIS to send the X-Frame-Options header, add this your site's Web.config file:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <!-- ... -->

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  <!-- ... -->
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is a more suitable answer.  No code needed just configuration

Comment: Hi, I just added the code into the my web.config source file. But after run the program, I couldn't see the X-Frame-Options on the Chrome test tool. Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you restart IIS / IIS Express after doing so?  In theory it isn't necessary since IIS tends to recycle when you change the web.config, but I've been bit by assuming before.

Comment: To effectively prevent framing attacks, the application should return a response header with the name X-Frame-Options and the value DENY to prevent framing altogether, or the value SAMEORIGIN to allow framing only by pages on the same origin as the response itself. Note that the SAMEORIGIN header can be partially bypassed if the application itself can be made to frame untrusted websites.

Comment: Most modern Web browsers support the X-Frame-Options HTTP header. Ensure it's set on all web pages returned by your site (if you expect the page to be framed only by pages on your server (e.g. it's part of a FRAMESET) then you'll want to use SAMEORIGIN, otherwise if you never expect the page to be framed, you should use DENY. ALLOW-FROM allows specific websites to frame the web page in supported web browsers). See also here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to do that. create a custom HttpModule like below:

```
    public class XframeOptionsModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += this.OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
    }
    private void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "Deny");
    }
}
```

then register this module in web.config

```
    <modules >
        <add name ="XframeOptions" type="your module's full type info"/>
    </modules>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because you are using the wrong method name instead of `OnResultExecuting` use `OnResultExecuted`.
You should write your method like this:

```
public class XframeOptionsFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "Deny");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NWebsec lets you set this and other security headers through web.config, OWIN middleware, and/or MVC filter attributes: https://github.com/NWebsec/NWebsec/wiki

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the project.

Comment: But standard .Net *lets you set this and other security headers through web.config*...?

Answer (score 0):

To add deny "x-frame-options" header to all MVC app you can do the following to avoid a Clickjacking attack.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Demo.Website.Modules
{
    public class XfoHeaderModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders += ContextPreSendRequestHeaders;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        private void ContextPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "Deny");
        }
    }
}
```

Add the below to the web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="XfoHeader" type="Demo.Website.Modules.XfoHeaderModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

[image]

Comment: It's best to stay away from the PreSendRequestHeaders event as it has been deprecated. See:http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet,-and-what-to-do-instead#presend

Comment: Your response in your screen shot has 2 X-Frame-Options headers. [This would be invalid](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034#section-2)