# 500 error when adding security policy of "upgrade-insecure-requests;" in webserver configuration

Tags: asp.net, content-security-policy

I am getting a mixed content error on my ASP website, so I am trying to resolve this by adding a security policy in the webserver configuration. However, whenever I add the below line, I am getting a 500 error. Anything I am doing wrong?

I am adding the above line inside my customHeaders. I read that I can have a multiple Content-Security-Policy and I assume it will not be an issue.

```js
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105445/1233379 -->
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <!-- Protects against MIME-type confusion attack. ref.: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/ -->
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <!-- CSP modern XSS directive-based defence, used since 2014. ref.: http://content-security-policy.com/ -->
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; connect-src *; font-src * data:; frame-src *; img-src * data:; media-src *; object-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';" />
        <!--Fix the mixed content issue. -->
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="upgrade-insecure-requests;"/>
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet -->
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
        <!-- Prevents from leaking referrer data over insecure connections. ref.: https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/ -->
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="same-origin" />
        <!--Feature-Policy is a new header that allows a site to control which features and APIs can be used in the browser. ref.: https://wicg.github.io/feature-policy/ -->
        <add name="Feature-Policy" value="accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment *; usb 'none'" />
      </customHeaders>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by putting it on the same line.

```js
<customHeaders>
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105445/1233379 -->
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <!-- Protects against MIME-type confusion attack. ref.: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/ -->
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <!-- CSP modern XSS directive-based defence, used since 2014. ref.: http://content-security-policy.com/ -->
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src 'self'; connect-src *; font-src * data:; frame-src *; img-src * data:; media-src *; object-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet -->
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
        <!-- Prevents from leaking referrer data over insecure connections. ref.: https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/ -->
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="same-origin" />
        <!--Feature-Policy is a new header that allows a site to control which features and APIs can be used in the browser. ref.: https://wicg.github.io/feature-policy/ -->
        <add name="Feature-Policy" value="accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment *; usb 'none'" />
 </customHeaders>
```

Comment: Now, to be consistently consistent, you could replace the deprecated `X-Frame-Options` header with the more powerful `frame-ancestors` CSP directive.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!